# Electronjs Multi Printing

Tags: javascript, windows, printing, electron, ipc

I have a web application, I need when take order then printout from desktop with ElectronJS desktop App.

But I have 3 printers and 3 Sections for order

Sample :

Pants Section,
Socks Section,
T-Shirt Section

When I get order like this : 2 Panths, 3 Socks, 1 T-Shirt

I need printout 3 order invoice own section printer

When I try this only I get 1 printout first order section:

```
_.forEach(printList, (printer)=>{
            let deviceName = printer.name;
            win.webContents.print(
                {
                    deviceName: deviceName,
                    silent: true,
                    printBackground: true,
                },
                (success, error) => {
                    if (success) {
                        resolve(true);
                    } else {
                        reject(true);
                    }
                }
            );
        });
```

I need multiple printer app with electronjs for desktop